# Node search for file upwards

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a function in node.js to search upwards in the filesystem to check if a given file exists and if so get its content.

For example, if I have the following folder structure:

`* root
|--dir1
| |-dir2
|  |-dir3
|...`

If I'm in dir3 I want to search for a given file that could be in any folder if I go up `..` but not in their subfolders. So what I want is a simple way to check in current folder for the file if it doesn't exist go up one folder and search there, until you find the file or you are in the root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easy to write by yourself. You can use `fs.readdir` or `fs.readdirSync`.
Synchronous solution might look like this: (not tested)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var process = require('process');
var path = require('path');
function findFile(filename, startdir) {
    if(!startdir) statdir = process.cwd();
    while(true) {
        var list = fs.readdirSync(startdir);
        if((index = list.indexOf(filename)) != -1)
            // found
            return fs.readFileSync(path.join([startdir, filename]));
        else if(startdir == '/')
            // root dir, file not found
            return null;
        else
            startdir = path.normalize(path.join([startdir, '..']));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also an NPM package - [fileUp](https://github.com/sindresorhus/find-up) that does this.

From the Readme:

```
const path = require('path');
const findUp = require('find-up');

(async () => {
    console.log(await findUp('unicorn.png'));
    //=> '/Users/sindresorhus/unicorn.png'

    console.log(await findUp(['rainbow.png', 'unicorn.png']));
    //=> '/Users/sindresorhus/unicorn.png'

    console.log(await findUp(async directory => {
        const hasUnicorns = await findUp.exists(path.join(directory, 'unicorn.png'));
        return hasUnicorns && directory;
    }, {type: 'directory'}));
    //=> '/Users/sindresorhus'
})();
```